# having trouble making a yolov5 object detection iOS app

Tags: macos, github, machine-learning, yolov5

I'm following [this tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-build-a-yolov5-object-detection-app-on-ios-39c8c77dfe58) but I'm having some issues with my Mac silicon M2 chip (not sure if this is the problem) I've cloned the GitHub repo and installed dependencies manually. but every time I do the next step in the terminal:

```
python export-nms.py --include coreml --weights yolov5n.pt
```

I get the same error:

> CoreML: export failure: MLModel of type mlProgram cannot be loaded just from the model spec object. It also needs the path to the weights file. Please provide that as well, using the 'weights_dir' argument.

I've tried changing my version of Python to the one that the tutorial used but this isn't working, I also tried

```
python export-nms.py --weights /Users/oscarcanning-thompson/Documents/app/yolov5/yolov5n.pt --include coreml
```

which ChatGPT gave me (last resort) and that didn't work either
Maybe I've put the weights file location wrong. I don't know what this is.